# Background Rotation inside ImageView (Android Studio - Java)

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation

I am trying to develop android application. However, I faced with an issue and it is I want to rotate the colorful square **background** 360 degrees. It is going to be animation effect. Continuously rotate. Is it possible?

I tried view.animate().rotate() but of course , it rotates imageview. I just want to rotate background drawable in imageview.

[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1IPj.png)

**Activity layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Background(@drawable/border)**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@color/colorYellowGreen"
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerColor="@color/colorBlue"
    android:startColor="@color/colorPink" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used rotate tag in animation-list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:duration="3000">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="180"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"/>
</item>
<item
    android:duration="3000">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="180"
        android:toDegrees="270"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"/>
</item>
<item
    android:duration="3000">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"/>
</item>
<item
    android:duration="3000">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:drawable="@drawable/border"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"/>
</item>

</animation-list>
```

The code above may be optinal but this is the most important part for **continously** rotation

```
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable =
(AnimationDrawable) mQRImage.getBackground();
animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(3000);
animationDrawable.start();
```