# Moving colors Android Studio

Tags: java, android, animation, background, android-drawable

i am developing an android application. In this application i want to move colors as in the picture below.[image: Colors]

1)I've tried to rotate background drawable:[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077436/background-rotation-inside-imageview-android-studio-java)

2)I've tried animation-list but this wasn't the solution.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:contentDescription="@string/qr"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
```

**@drawable/border**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@color/colorYellowGreen"
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerColor="@color/colorBlue"
    android:startColor="@color/colorPink" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

***NOTE:*** I am not looking for rotating view. Because there is content inside imageview. So **do not** suggest to use ViewPropertyAnimator class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be the gradient with a timer.
Here are two examples, one changes the colors and the other changes the angle hence creating a rotation effect.

You can tweak them for your purposes.

But be wary of the performance depending on how fast you want it to change.

**Rotation effect**

```
//Call this once to change gradient angle
private fun startAngleChangeJob() {
    var shape = imageView.background
    var borderGrad = shape as GradientDrawable

    var timer = fixedRateTimer("colorTimer", false, 0L, 100) {
        var ori = borderGrad.orientation.ordinal
        var newOri = (ori + 1) % 7

        this@BorderActivity.runOnUiThread {
            borderGrad.orientation = GradientDrawable.Orientation.values()[newOri]
        }
    }
}
```

**Color change effect**

```
//Call this once in onCreate to change gradient colors
private fun startColorChangeJob() {
    var timer = fixedRateTimer("colorTimer", false, 0L, 100) {
        var shape = imageView.background
        var borderGrad = shape as GradientDrawable
        var colors = borderGrad.colors
        var colorsNew = IntArray(colors!!.size)
        for (i in colors.indices) {
            var newInd = (i + 1) % colors.size
            colorsNew[newInd] = colors[i]
        }
        this@BorderActivity.runOnUiThread {
            borderGrad.colors = colorsNew
        }
    }
}
```

**Color shift effect**

```
for (i in colors.indices) {
            var oldColor = Color.valueOf(colors[i])
            var red = (oldColor.red() + 0.2f) % 1.0f
            var green = (oldColor.green() + 0.2f) % 1.0f
            var blue = (oldColor.blue() + 0.2f) % 1.0f
            colorsNew[i] = Color.argb(1.0f, red, green, blue)
        }
```

Comment: I am developing with java so what should i use instead of fixedRateTimer

Comment: You can use Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)

Comment: Both of them are working properly but could we make transactions continuously. In this code how can i reduce distances when switching between colors. They jump immediately and i dont want it.

Comment: That means if the rotation angle changes by 45 , how can we reduce it to 1

Comment: Orientation works on an enum, so values are fixed and there are only 8 options.
For that effect you may need to change the color codes of your colors.
See the update to my answer and for the color loop use the one specified as **Color shift effect**

Comment: Hey, I have also found a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224797/how-to-animate-gradient). Also color shift  effect did not work. Thanks for replying and sharing your solutions.